# Activity not observing update to LiveData from ViewModel (MVVM)

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-livedata

If anyone can see something wrong with my implementation I would greatly appreciate knowing what it is. The activity does not seem to be observing updates to the MutableLiveData I am making.

**ViewModel**

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

   val myLiveData: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
       MutableLiveData<String>()
   }

   fun updateData(newValue: String) {
       myLiveData.postValue(newValue)
   }
}
```

**Activity**

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    myViewModel.myLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
        myTextView.text = it
    })
    
}}
```

I know **updateData** works because if I call it form the activity with an arbitrary string it updates the UI.

Comment: You said your problem is it’s not updating, but then in your last sentence you say it *is* updating, so what is the actual problem? By the way, using `lazy` to create such a trivial class instance is pointless. The Lazy instance itself is just as heavy to instantiate as the MutableLiveData would be if you instantiated it directly. You don’t need to include that extra complexity.

Comment: I said the problem is the UI isn't observing updates, the LiveData value is updating fine. I'm following the recommended implementation of LiveData per the dev docs.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: I don’t understand the distinction. It’s getting updated through your observer in the above code.

Comment: calling updateData() in the viewModel successfully updates the value of the MutableLiveData (shown through logging), but the Activity does not observe this update.

Comment: I think you've stripped out too much code to be able to tell what's wrong. The code above doesn't have any issues besides that it's not showing `myTextView` defined anywhere (although maybe you're using a synthetic reference). It might help to show how you're logging to confirm that the live data is getting updated.

Comment: So what was your solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're using lazy in your code. Try to use equals instead of it.

Comment: Could you please ellaborate with some code examples?

Answer (score -4):

In your `.observe`, you are missing the new value which is being returned whenever your live data updates.

```
myViewModel.myLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
    myTextView.text = it
})
```

It should look like this, where "it" can be named anything:

```
myViewModel.myLiveData.observe(this, Observer { it ->
    myTextView.text = it
})
```